# How to loop 3 column in one row in laravel vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to display the bellow dev in three columns with different data while data looped, like this image:

[image]

```html
  <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-lg-4"  v-for="emp in employees" :key="emp.id">
                <div class="text-center card-box"> 
                    <div class="member-card pt-2 pb-2">
                        <div class="thumb-lg member-thumb mx-auto"><img :src="'/img/profile/' +emp.employee_photo" 
                          class="rounded-circle img-thumbnail" alt="profile-image"></div>
                        <div class="">
                            <h4> {{emp.first_name}}  {{emp.last_name}} </h4>
                            <p class="text-muted">@Founder <span>| </span>
                            <span><a href="#" class="text-pink">websitename.com</a></span></p>
                        </div> 
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 btn-rounded waves-effect w-md waves-light">Message Now</button>
               
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please use these suggestions to ask questions 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I have created an example with some dummy data. You can look into the following one-

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        employees: [
          {
            employee_photo: "https://picsum.photos/510/300?random",
            first_name: "Monica Meki",
            last_name: "Galler",
          },
          {
            employee_photo: "https://picsum.photos/510/300?random",
            first_name: "Pheobe Zen",
            last_name: "Buffay",
          },
          {
            employee_photo: "https://picsum.photos/510/300?random",
            first_name: "Rachel Caren",
            last_name: "Green",
          },
        ],
    },
});
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
<div id="app">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm" v-for="emp in employees" :key="emp.id">
        <div class="text-center card-box">
          <div class="member-card pt-2 pb-2">
            <div class="thumb-lg member-thumb mx-auto">
              <img
                :src="emp.employee_photo"
                class="rounded-circle img-thumbnail"
                alt="profile-image"
              />
            </div>

            <div class="">
              <h4>{{ emp.first_name }} {{ emp.last_name }}</h4>
              <p class="text-muted">
                @Founder <span>| </span>
                <span><a href="#" class="text-pink">websitename.com</a></span>
              </p>
            </div>

            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary mt-3 btn-rounded waves-effect w-md waves-light"
            >
              Message Now
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please don't add link only answer because in future this link may be unavailable, so please add relevant code example that addresses the issue